# App restarting on changing orientation change using react-native-orientation-locker

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-orientation-locker

I am using react-native-orientation-locker for changing the orientation of my app depending on the screen, I am calling the functions via useEffects in the different components. On certain android devices my app restarts when the orientation changes, this behaviour is not consistent but happens on a couple of Android devices. What could be the possible causes?

Comment: Is the app restarting, or the Activity?  The Activity restarting is standard behavior on rotation for all Android devices, and has been since Android version 1.  There's ways to turn that off, but it isn't recommended.

Comment: The js thread of the app restarts

Comment: sounds like Activity recreation-  if the activity is recreated, all views and other resources of the Activity are recreated.  Since the interpreter is owned by the activity, it's going to be recreated as well.  Which means unless you're serializing and reinstantiating your state somehow, you'll appear to restart.

Comment: From my logs on android studio Window manager is not able to communicate back to the app.